# ggplot2 shade colors according to column values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
cond <- gl(15,1,labels=c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"))
pos <-c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5),rep("c",5))
mean <- c(3.202634, 3.819009, 3.287785, 4.531127, 3.093865, 3.360535, 4.084791, 3.886960, 3.297692, 4.281323, 2.418745, 3.759699, 3.553860, 4.812989, 1.606597)
hd <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)

df <- data.frame(cond,pos,mean,hd)
```

...and generated this plot

```
library(ggplot2)
b <- ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y = mean, fill=pos))  + labs(x = "X", y="Y", fill=NULL)
c <- b + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") + theme(text = element_text(size=18), axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size = 14)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") 

my_theme <- theme_update(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey90"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Now I would like to adjust the colors according to the `hd` column of the dataframe such that every column of the barplot gets a slightly darker shade of the respective color (e.g. dark red instead of red) if `hd=="TRUE"`.

How can I achieve that?

And an additional question: How can I increase the distance between the `labs` X and Y and the plot/the axes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use function `interaction()` inside `aes()` to provide fill= values as combination of `hd` and `pos`. And then with `scale_fill_manual()` provide colors.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y = mean, fill=interaction(hd,pos)))  + 
  labs(x = "X", y="Y", fill=NULL)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","darkred","blue","darkblue","green","darkgreen"))
```

To change position of axis title, inside function `theme()` use `axis.title=` for both or `axis.title.x/axis.title.y` for separately x/y axis titles and then `vjust=`. Values form 0 and lower will put titles lower. To ensure that there will be place for the labels you can increase plot margins with `plot.margin=` (you have to add `library(grid)` to use function unit).

```
library(grid)
your.plot + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,2,2),"cm"))+
            theme(axis.title=element_text(vjust=0))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I looked for, thank you very much. `vjust` values below 0 push the axis text out of the plot canvas (at least in my case). Is it possible to avoid this / enlarge the canvas?

Comment: +1 - another possibility is to use alpha transparency, although with gridlines in the background this sometimes does not look very nice when they show through.